# Gstreamer RTP header

Tags: gstreamer

I am sending RTP audio mono stream with S16LE at 8 ks/s using RTPL16PAY. One test is sending audiotestsrc at 440 Hz. This results in a continuous packet size of 566 bytes.  Wireshark says the protocol is SKYPE. The first word of the RTP payload is 0x8060 which agree with the specified load type of 96.  According to the RFC3550 there should be another 14 bytes of header information before the streamed data starts.  However the data starts 11 bytes later which is odd in a couple of ways. I have looked at a few packets   Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Please see [ask]. The idea is you show some code that illustrates the problem you need help with.

Comment: gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audio/x-raw, rate =8000, format = S16LE, channels=1 ! audiorate! audioconvert ! rtpL16pay ! udpsink host= 192.168.1.148 port=5001

Comment: I am using the above command.  I am trying to find when the data starts in the RTP stream.  What I see in wireshark does not agree with the RFC 3550

Comment: Details like this should be in the question. It's unclear if your question is about programming or not, though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol#Packet_header without any extras the header is 12 bytes in total. Sounds about right.

Comment: I count 11 bytes before that digitized data starts.  How does one look at the code?